# ¿como modifico el geom_bar para que aparezcan todas las áreas en la gráfica?

Tags: r, rstudio, ggplot2

Mi código es este:

```
ggplot(trabajadores, aes(x=periodo, group=1))+geom_area(aes(y=informales, fill="Informales"),position = position_dodge2(width = .90))+geom_area(aes(y=ocupada, fill="Ocupadas"),position = position_dodge2(width = .70))+geom_area(aes(y=desocupada, fill="Desocupadas"),position = position_dodge2(width = .50))+geom_area(aes(y=total, fill="Total"),position = position_dodge2(width = .30))+theme(axis.text.x = element_text(color="black",size=8, angle=90))+scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(5000000,10000000,15000000,20000000,25000000,30000000,35000000,40000000,45000000,50000000,55000000),limits=c(0,60000000), labels = comma)+labs(title = "Distribución de la Población Economicamente Activa para México",subtitle = "Total de personas",x= "Año",y="personas",caption = "Fuente: elaboración propia con datos de INEGI")+theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.box = "horizontal", legend.title=element_blank())
```

y me aparece la siguiente gráfica:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A lo mejor, me compliqué mucho la vida escribiendo el código tan largo, pero la ayuda que me gustaría que me proporcionaran es ¿Como hago que las áreas de las demás áreas, se vean abajo de la curva morada?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero es que siempre es ideal compartir un pequeño fragmento de los datos con los que quieres resolver tu problema, la función `dput(df)` es útil en ese sentido.

Por otro lado, una recomendación es suprimir el campo `total` del gráfico, porque es este tipo de visualizaciones se entiende que el total es es la acumulación de las diferentes categorías. Por otro lado, ayudaría utilizar la función `tidyr::gather()` para acomodar las diferentes categorias de trabajadores en una sola columna.

A continuación un pequeño ejemplo que solucionaría tu problema.

```
 library(tidyr)
    library(dplyr)
    library(ggplot2)

 # Data de ejemplo (recomendado siempre que vayas a preguntar algo)

    trabajadores <- data.frame(desocupados = seq(1000, 10000, 1000),
                               ocupados = seq(2000, 20000, 2000),
                               periodo = 2001:2010) %>% mutate(total = desocupados + ocupados)


    trabajadores %>%
      select(-total) %>%
      gather(key = "condicion",
             value = "personas",
             -periodo) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = periodo, y = personas, fill = condicion)) + geom_area()
```

Otra forma de ver el resultado con el codigo original es ajustar el atributo `geom_area(alpha = 0.5)` en cada geom. Aunque te repito, esta es la forma más compleja de llegar a tu objetivo.

Comment: Muchas gracias Johan. Ya lo pude resolver de las dos maneras, pero, si, la forma mas complicada es mover cada geom, y muchas gracias por la corrección de como formular la pregunta, en un futuro asi será.

Comment: Estamos para ayudar, me alegra que haya funcionado. Quedo a la orden para cualquier pregunta en el futuro.